# I don't understand this keyword in this context in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, this

In the code below, what in the world is the this object?  It is referencing h1, but if I write `h1.innerHMTL` it doesn't work.
Or if I write `document.getElementByTagName("h1").innerHTML = 'Oops!'`

it doesn't work either.

What is "this" referencing, can someone write it out.  I'm just confused.

```html
<!-- Works -->

<h1 onclick="this.innerHTML='Ooops!'">Click on this text!</h1>

<!-- Works -->

<h1 onclick="myFunctional()" id="demo">Click on this text!</h1>

<script>
function myFunctional() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Ooops!";
}
</script>

<!-- Not working -->

<h1 onclick="myFunction()">Click on this text!</h1>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "Ooops!";
}
</script>

<!-- Not Working -->

<h1 onclick="document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = 'Ooops!';">Click on 
this text!</h1>

<!--Testing this one -->

<h1 onclick="document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = 'Ooops!';">Click on 
this text!</h1>

<!--Your answer does not work -->
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a DOM0 event handler like that is called, the browser ensures that `this` is set to a reference to the element the handler is on. So in your code there, `this` is the `h1` element instance. `this.innerHTML = 'Ooops!'` sets the content of the element to the "Ooops!"

> In the code above, what in the world is the this object?

It's in the DOM.

> It is referencing `h1`, but if I write `h1.innerHMTL` it doesn't work.

That's because you don't have an `h1` variable. See my note above about why `this` works in that situation. (There's also a type in `innerHTML` there.)

> Or if I write `document.getElementByTagName("h1").innerHTML = 'Oops!'` it doesn't work.

There is no `getElementByTagName` method in the DOM. There's `getElementsByTagName` (note the plural), which [returns a **list**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method) of all `h1`s in the document.

You could use `querySelector`, which returns the first match for any CSS selector in the document:

```
document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "Ooops!";
```

More about the various DOM methods available to you can be found in [MDN's DOM documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) for details.

Comment: Okay, the h1.innerhtml was silly of me, but are you saying that if I replace this with document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "Ooops!";it should work?

Comment: @fortunata: Yes, see the linked MDN pages for details. (And if you're doing this in an `onclick="...."` attribute, you'll need to make sure the quotes are correct. But it's best to use modern event handling instead.)

Comment: Can you please help me correct the onclick statement with your query selector.  It just doesn't seem to work and I always get an error.  I just want to see it function.

Comment: I updated the code trying to use your query selection method but I can't get it to work.  Can you please briefly check and make the correction or tell me what I am doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @fortunata: As I said above: *"And if you're doing this in an `onclick="...."` attribute, you'll need to make sure the quotes are correct..."* You've used `"` inside `"`, which won't work. You need to do what you did with the `this` example, and use `'` within `"` (or `"` within `'`): `<h1 onclick="document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = 'Ooops!';">Click on this text!</h1>` (Or you can use `&quot;` for the inner ones, but it's harder to read.)

Comment: Well, guess what?  I copy pasted your answer in and ran it and it doesn't work...  lol

Comment: never mind it actually works, I tried in a separate .js file but for some reason it isn't working in the snippet code, I'm assuming there's a hidden h1 tag somewhere and it's changing that h1...  Ok, so I'll give you the check mark. Thanks for the help.